# PhoneGap: Is it possible to reference video files located in Documents folder from html in www directory in iOS?

Tags: html, cordova, html5-video

I have an app where I need to download video files from an external server as the videos are too large to fit into the app itself as it will exceed the allowable file size for an app. I need to be able to play these video files from within the app which is simply an HTML 5 page that allows a user to swipe between divs (like a keynote presentation).  On one of the presentation "pages" there are links to the video files. I've tried referencing the file relative to the html file like so:

```
<video controls="controls" poster="assets/videos/01_intro_eng.jpg" width="768" height="432" title="01_intro_eng">
<source src="./../../Documents/01_intro_eng.m4v" type="video/mp4" id="vid1" />
</video>
```

I also tried:

```
<video controls="controls" poster="assets/videos/01_intro_eng.jpg" width="768" height="432" title="01_intro_eng">
<source src="../../Documents/01_intro_eng.m4v" type="video/mp4" id="vid1" />
</video>
```

When I click on the image to play the video, it simply gives me the poster image with a strikethrough on the video player.

Referencing the video files inside the www directory plays them without an issue, so there's nothing wrong with the files themselves.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

iExplorer image is included below for reference. The html file referencing the video files located in Documents is called app.html (located in www directory)

[image]

Comment: The documents folder path inside the app is different path from install to install so you can't recursively back your way out of the WWW folder. 

How are you downloading the videos ?

Comment: Thanks Adam.  I'm using:
`
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download();
`
As far as I know there's no way to download directly into the www folder is there?

Comment: No unfortunately its a security thing on IOS. You would need to work out the file path location of your Documents folder using the File API.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam. Do you know if it's possible to move files from the Documents folder into the www folder? I'm guessing not for security reasons as well. I need to be able to reference the videos in the Documents folder to play them, but I'm not sure how I can do that as I'm referencing them from HTML. Maybe via javascript?

Comment: So I figured out how to get the path from within the HTML and I'm using jQuery to update the src path.

Comment: Hello. What path did you use to reference the videos from your html document? Thanks.